# Read file from shared path with Authentication as Java.io.File

Tags: java, java-io, smb, pgp, jcifs

I have an encryption class (PGP Encryption util) which accepts only java.io.File object. The inner methods(which is in jar) which is used for encryption are accepting only java.io.File as argument.

I need to read a file from shared path in which authentication needed to access and ancrypt the same file and write back to same shared path. So I am using jcifs for file read. It reads file as SmbFile Format.

I have 2 doubts here

1) Is it possible to convert SmbFile to java.io.File, without writing the content to an actual file(not even temporary file)? and pass the File object to the file encrypting method as below.

```
File someFile = ConvertSmbFileToFile(SmbFile smb);
pgpEncryptionService.encryptFile(someFile,true);
```

2) If the above is not possible Is it possible to do PGP encryption with SmbFile type as input? can somebody share the relevant link?

My project security wants only encrypted files to get transferred through network. So writing the SmbFile to java.io.File is not seems to be an option.
Even Writing to a temporary file is like allowing the non-encrypted data to transfer through network layer. So temporary file too is out of scope.

Comment: Have you considered running the program as the authenticated user and thereby having "built in" access to the share?

Answer (score 0):

SMB 3 and above (3.1.1) supports encryption/decryption so you can use a SMB lib that supports those SMB dialects. (SMB 3 supports ccm algorithm and 3.1.1 supports gcm) you just need to make sure that the other host supports SMB3 and above.

If I'm not mistaken only Visuality Systems [jNQ](https://www.visualitynq.com/products/jnq-java-smb-client) product support those SMB dialects.

And I think that jCIFS and jNQ supports `OutStream` and `InputStream` so maybe you can use this instead of java.io.file

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the intent is to encrypt file rather than to encrypt SMB traffic. Then the  solution may be a wrapper class around SmbFile that extends java.io.File. I guess that all you need is to implement getInputStream() through the same method of SmbFile.